# Объединение SELECT и таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы: задачи и кол-во часов для каждой из задач в конкретную дату:

```
task (id_task, id_user, id_object) 
task_hours (id_task, date, hours)
```

Выборкой получаю подсчет часов для каждой из задач в промежуток времени:

```
SELECT  task_hours.id_task AS taskId, SUM(task_hours.hours) AS summ 
FROM task_hours 
WHERE task_hours.date >=1519851600 AND   task_hours.date < 1522443600
GROUP BY task_hours.id_task
```

Каким образом можно объединить получившийся запрос с таблицей `task`, чтобы результат выглядел как:

```
id_task, id_user, id_object, summ
```

Comment: про [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) не знаешь в принципе или не осилил для этого запроса?

Comment: если честно, то не осилил ... учусь ... JOIN соединяет только, если столбцы одинаковые (кол-во). Не нашел готового примера как соединить таблицу и SELECT. Например t1 JOIN t2 ON (и вот тут идет обращение к t1 и t2 ), а как быть, если вместо t1 выступает SELECT (указанный в вопросе) я не понял. AS на результат запроса можно повесить?

Comment: В данном случае join можно сделать до группировки, т.е. `SELECT  task_hours.id_task AS taskId, SUM(task_hours.hours) AS summ, ...
FROM task_hours 
JOIN task ON task.id_task=task_hours.id_task
WHERE task_hours.date >=1519851600 AND   task_hours.date < 1522443600
GROUP BY task_hours.id_task` результат будет тот же (поля, которые добавятся в спискок выборки стоит добавить и в group by). И конечно можно сделать join с подзапросом `select ... from task t join (select ... group by ..) x ON t.task_id=x.task_id`

Answer (score 0):

То что ты хочешь сделать называется [подзапрос](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) (а точнее [`derived tables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html), не помню русский термин), для начала вариант с оным:

```
SELECT  th.taskId, t.id_user, t.id_object, th.summ 
(   SELECT  task_hours.id_task AS taskId, SUM(task_hours.hours) AS summ 
    FROM task_hours 
    WHERE task_hours.date >=1519851600 AND   task_hours.date < 1522443600
    GROUP BY task_hours.id_task ) AS th
JOIN task AS t ON th.id_task == t.id_task
```

Но использовать его совсем не обязательно: `mysql` [допускает](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) присутствие обычных столбцов в `GROUP BY`-запросах, а так как ты группируешь по первичному ключу таблицы `task`(я надеюсь), то значения всех таких столбцов будут однозначны, а запрос упрощается до:

```
SELECT  th.id_task AS taskId, t.id_user, t.id_object, SUM(th.hours) AS summ 
FROM task_hours AS th JOIN task AS t ON th.id_task == t.id_task
WHERE th.date >=1519851600 AND  th.date < 1522443600
GROUP BY th.id_task
```

Если есть вопрос, что из этого более производительно, то почти наверняка (математический термин) оптимизатор запросов выстроит их планы одинаково, так что производительностью они отличаться не будут, но предпочтительна всё же вторая форма — она требует от оптимизатора быть чуточку менее умным.